# Get Eclipse code working with Authenticated Proxy

Tags: java, eclipse, authentication, proxy

I'm trying to get my Java code in Eclipse to access the internet, through an authenticated proxy.  My code is simply reading a website source using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Here are the things I already tried:
- In Preferences, setting the HTTP and HTTPS proxy, clearing SOCKS, and going to Manual
- In Eclipse.ini, adding

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttp.proxyHost=XXX
-Dhttp.proxyUser=XXX
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=XXX
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
```

Comment: You are aware that it is `-Dhttp.proxyHost` and not `Dhttp.proxyHost`?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes I am aware, edited into my post now

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware that what you are setting, is the settings for the JVM in which *Eclipse* runs.  Your programs are started in *another* JVM where these settings do not apply.

Running your application creates a launch configuration, which you can open and add the system properties you need.  They will then apply when that launch configuration is launched.

(also, Eclipse has a very elaborate network settings panel in the preferences window where you can configure this for Eclipse itself).

Comment: Could you give more specific directions for modifying the launch configuration?